# Entity framework connects to master database for contained database user

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a [**contained** database user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable). Since it's contained in the database it's not allowed to connect to any other database including master. Unfortunately Entity Framework seems to connect to the master database anyway.

I've created a new console app with the latest Entity Framework nuget (6.2.0) to make sure nothing else connects to the master database:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionString = "Server=sql-azure.database.windows.net;Database='Database';User ID=Username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;";
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString))
    {
        dbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 10 * 60;
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC cleanup @Date", new SqlParameter("@Date", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-3)));
    }
}
```

How do I force Entity Framework to not connect to the master database? I get failures in the audit logs on the master database which causes azure threat detection to go off.

Comment: your problem? your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching some more I've disabled the database initializer before the using statement like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
```

With this line of code, the console app doesn't connect to the master database any more. [More info about Database.SetInitializer(null)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710864/151025).

Full example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionString = "Server=sql-azure.database.windows.net;Database='Database';User ID=Username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;";
    Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString))
    {
        dbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 10 * 60;
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC cleanup @Date", new SqlParameter("@Date", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-3)));
    }
}
```

Comment: wait wait wait...so you have to make a coding change to switch to a Contained Database User?  That should definitely be handled through the driver and the provider

Comment: at least in my experience, Entity Framework requires read access to master in order so that it can get information about the objects in the user database. In order for me to use contained database user account with entity framework, I had to create a user in the master database and have that user associated with the same login as the one used to access the user database. Note: no need to grant permissions to the user in the master database- the necessary tables are already public.

Answer (score 1):

The below would work for MS SQL on premises as well as if you are on SQL Azure:

```
use master;    
CREATE LOGIN DemoUser WITH PASSWORD = 'DemoPassword';
GO
CREATE USER DemoUser FOR LOGIN DemoUser
GO

use DemoDB;
CREATE USER DemoUser FOR LOGIN DemoUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER DemoUser; 
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER DemoUser;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro that:

Contained user:

```
//create user joe with password ='xxxxxx'



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ef6Test
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;database=adventureworks;uid=joe;pwd=xxxx";
            using (var dbContext = new DbContext(connectionString))
            {
                dbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 10 * 60;
                Console.WriteLine(dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select db_name() dbname;").Single());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the audit logs and make sure it doesn't connect to the master database? The code I posted above is working so it doesn't throw exceptions or anything.